# Using Firebase signInWithRedirect can I configure it to redirect me back to a specific page

Tags: firebase, angularfire2

When I call

`this.afAuth.auth.signInWithRedirect(provider)
      .then((credential) => {
      })
      .catch((error) => this.handleError(error));`

The redirect works correctly and is handled by firebase returning me to the login page. However it takes a while for the promise to complete

`this.afAuth.auth.getRedirectResult().then((result) => {
 //Login or move to request additional info
});`

As the page has completely refreshed, I have no info that lets me know the page should not be showing login buttons, but instead should be showing a loading state.

Has anyone found a nice way to resolve this and hold the loading state, my initial attempt was to use angular routing to pass through a loading state, but annoyingly the signInWithRedirect service doesn't seem to change the url it redirects to.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[FirebaseUI](https://github.com/firebase/firebaseui-web) uses local storage to maintain whether to show the loading state or not ([source](https://github.com/firebase/firebaseui-web/blob/33b7c7c9d4e4302fac3d21ccfcc1906696406573/javascript/widgets/authui.js#L415)). You should be able to do the same. However, if you don't want to handle local storage and don't mind polluting the URL, you can always add a unique query/hash param to URL before calling `signInWithRedirect` (Firebase Auth serializes the current URL and passes it as `redirect_uri` to the OAuth endpoint ([source](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.OAuthProvider#setCustomParameters)).

Example using hash param

```
// you can use any string here; just make sure to use the same one after reload
window.location.hash = "redirecting"
this.afAuth.auth.signInWithRedirect(provider)
  .then((credential) => {
  })
  .catch((error) => this.handleError(error));
```

Then you can just check right after your component is rendered (after redirect):

```
this.loading = (window.location.hash === "redirecting")
// Clear the hash
window.location.hash = ""
```

Hope this helps.

### Edit

You can also achieve setting the redirect URL to whatever you want by using `window.history.replaceState` and `window.history.pushState` to change the URL right before redirecting (similar to hash example above).

Comment: Really good point in the edit, if the url for redirect is taken from window.location we could simply just change it without causing a full browser refresh, prior to the redirects. For our usage in angular(6) we could change the url without a refresh by instead of using the router using location.go()

Answer (score 1):

One way to achieve this is by using rxjs.

```
<div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="center center" style="height: 100%">
    <mat-card
        *ngIf="!(authService.pendingRedirect$ | async); else loading"
        fxFlex="40"
        fxFlex.lt-md="60"
        fxFlex.lt-sm="90"
        fxFlex.lt-sm="90"
        style="margin: 20px"
    >
        <mat-tab-group mat-stretch-tabs dynamicHeight>
            <ng-container *ngIf="!(afAuth.authState | async) && showLoginRegister">
                <mat-tab label="Log in">
                    <ng-template [ngTemplateOutlet]="login"></ng-template>
                </mat-tab>
                <mat-tab label="Register">
                    <ng-template [ngTemplateOutlet]="register"></ng-template>
                </mat-tab>
            </ng-container>

            <mat-tab *ngIf="showResetPass" label="Reset Password">
                <ng-template [ngTemplateOutlet]="resetpass"></ng-template>
            </mat-tab>

            <ng-container *ngIf="afAuth.authState | async as user">
                <mat-tab *ngIf="!user.emailVerified" label="Verify Email">
                    <ng-template *ngTemplateOutlet="verifyEmail; context: { user: user }"></ng-template>
                </mat-tab>
            </ng-container>
        </mat-tab-group>
    </mat-card>
</div>


<ng-template #loading>
 <mat-progress-spinner mode="indeterminate" color="primary"></mat-progress-spinner>
</ng-template>
```

**.ts**

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class AuthService {
    pendingRedirect$ = new BehaviorSubject(false);
    user$ = new BehaviorSubject<User | null>(null);
    constructor(
        private afAuth: AngularFireAuth,
        private afs: AngularFirestore,
        private router: Router,
        private snack: MatSnackBar
    ) {
        this.user$.subscribe();
        this.pendingRedirect$.next(true);
        this.afAuth.authState
            .pipe(
                switchMap((user) => {
                    if (user) {
                        return this.afs
                            .doc<any>(`users/${user.uid}`)
                            .valueChanges()
                            .pipe(
                                tap((userDoc) => {
                                    if (router.url === '/' && userDoc.emailVerified) this.router.navigate(['/user']);
                                })
                            );
                    } else {
                        this.pendingRedirect$.next(false);
                        return of(null);
                    }
                })
            )
            .subscribe((user) => this.user$.next(user));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you have 2 separate login pages, one for redirects? You can then default to showing loading spinners/different UI while the promise resolves?

Comment: As said above, that's what I'd love todo - however as far as I can see the redirect service only allows redirects back to the same location.

Comment: true. I am also trying to solve the same